# kohana ORM relationship

Tags: orm, kohana, relationship, belongs-to

I have two tables.

```
Table1 { Column1, Column2 }

Table2 { Column1, Column2 }
```

And I have the relation as follows:

```
Table1.Column1 belongs_to Table2.Column2
```

So in Table1_Model:

```
protected $_belongs_to = array('Table2' => array('foreign_key' => 'Column1'));
```

But how should I specify that I want to connect this to Table2.Column2? Table2.Column2 is not the primary index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would have a relationship like that.

If table1 belongs to table2, then I would look at it as:

`Table1.Column2 belongs_to Table2.Column1`, because Table1.Column2 is a foreign key which links Table2 primary key.

So the relationship in Table1_Model would be:

`protected $_belongs_to = array('Table2' => array('foreign_key' => 'Column2'));`

More information here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships